# Adding an instance of NSButton to NSWindow programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am in the early stages of learning programming/Cocoa and I decided I want to create a simple UI programmatically so as to better visualize the relationship between code/GUI. I opened up the default template for Cocoa in OS X. My only modifications to the template so far are:

```
@property NSButton *theButton;
```

In Appdelegate.h
and

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    CGRect buttonFrame;

    buttonFrame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 15, 5);
    self.theButton = [[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:buttonFrame];
    [self.theButton setTitle:@"test"];
    [self.window addSubview:self.theButton];
    

}
```

In Appdelegate.m.

However I am getting the error:

> [self.window addSubview:self.theButton];
>
> No visible @interface for 'NSWindow' declares the selector 'addSubview:'

Why is this?

Comment: Is it `self.window.view`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because NSWindow doesn't have an addSubview: method. That method is part of NSView. You might want the window's contentView.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's a little different than it is on iOS. The tutorial I followed on iOS accomplished the same thing with [self.window addSubview:self.taskTable]; hence the confusion

Comment: I'd like to point out that while UIWindow on iOS has an addSubview, it should almost never be used for this. You would still want to add a button or any view to a UIView of some kind. Usually the rootViewController's view.

Answer (score 5):

NSWindow inherits from NSResponder so you can use like

`[self.window.contentView addSubview: yourbutton];`

But for UIWindow you can use. `[self.window addSubview:button]` because it inherits from UIView. Hope it will more clear...